# Could somebody fix my question and produce a copy of the answers?

Tags: support, questions

I have an interesting predicament. I asked [What does "information porn" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37236/what-does-information-porn-mean) with the word *porn* in the title, and the firewall on the computer I am using is blocking it. This means I am not able to view my question, the comments, the answers, or edit my question.

I accidentally pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> before I finished writing my question, so could somebody please edit it so it doesn't look as awkward and unfinished? If you do, could you link to this meta post so people know what's going on?

Also, could anyone be so kind and copy the answers and comments so that I can actually see them (link to a screenshot, or just post them as answers to this question)?

Comment: Why do you urgently need a question with "porn"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to a title change, consider using [timeline view](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/37236/timeline). This will give you the full detail of all the posts (although absent of convenient links to revision history and any ability to vote), and the title of the page will just be "Timeline" rather than containing the blocked word.

Do you have any recommendations on how to revise the title so as to retain the question you're asking without being incredibly vague? As it stands, the current title is very direct about what you're asking - removing the keyword that's being asked about would require supplying something that'll still be distinct enough to identify what the question is about.

Comment: `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37236/safe-title-goes-here` redirects to `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37236/what-does-information-porn-mean`. If you change the title so that the *o* in *porn* is an *◌* instead, I think it will fix the problem.

Comment: @Peter It'll fix the problem for your block but it'll ruin the searchability of the question, which is a fairly negative result. I don't recall it redirecting in the past, it must've changed somewhere down the line. I'll remove that part from my answer, but does the timeline view work for you?

Comment: yes, I suppose the timeline will work well enough. Thank you